# Issues with resizing of font using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have used this blog reference for resizing of font for a webpage but as soon as i use it in my html page it gives me error which is not traceable, may be it is jquery conflict

http://depotwebdesigner.com/scripts/how-to-use-jquery-to-create-a-font-resize.html

I have the following imports available

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/animatedcollapse.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.treeview.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>
```

I want to add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

As soon as i add this, the page distorts and some exception in knockout api comes.

Please let me know if it is a conflict situation and how to handle this?

Comment: i use  var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); at the top of any custom js I write to ensure no conflicts, not always but helps sometimes, if you are getting a conflict then this may help

Comment: it is not conflicting with custom js.. some other plugin is hampering it

Answer (score 0):

I myself used to meet this problem once before. And I figured out that some of the plugins does not support the new version of jquery. Then I changed `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>` to `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>` and it works.

**Note**: you will get jquery version 1.9.1 if you use `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>`.

Comment: So why u still use <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> ?

Comment: I have tried the either way removing -latest.js and removing 1.8.3.js also but it doesnt fire